# Top menustrip not showing in openerp edit form

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-7

I am stuck in a problem. I want to open edit form when a button is clicked, instead of the items form that i have selected from drop down.

Edit form is opening but there is not top menu strip ribbon that has `save` button to save the modifications made in the form.

Setting `'target':'inline'` in return of button function opened the form in edit mode.

I am not sure what i have missed. Please let me know if i am missing any attribute or something.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about a dropdown, I understand that you have a `many2one` field and you want to open a specific form when you click on the selected item, instead of opening the default form.

If that's what you wanted, you can do it without calling a python function, you will only need to modify the XML code:

```
<field name="your_many2one_field" context="{'form_view_ref': 'your_module.your_specific_form_xml_id',}"/>
```

Otherwise, if I didn't understand you well, try to return the next code in your python function:

```
return {
    'name': _('Any string you want'),
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form',
    'view_id': False,
    'views': [(form_view_id, 'form'), ],
    'res_model': 'your.model',
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'target': 'current',
    'flags': {'action_buttons': True},
}
```